# Prove $T(x)=0$ (Linear Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that for any five linear transformations mapping $\mathbb R^2$ into $\mathbb R^2$, there exists some non-zero scalars $r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4, r_5$ such that $T=r_1T_1+r_2T_2+r_3T_3+r_4T_4+r_5T_5$ such that $T(x)=0$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb R^2$.

What I did
$$T : \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$$
Let $$r\in\mathbb R^2 \qquad T[x,y]=[r_1x_1+...+r_5x_5, r_1y_1+...+r_5y_5]=[0,0]$$

I think that I should use independence to prove this, but I'm not sure how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The space of linear transformations from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ (remember these are also matrices of size $2 \times 2$) has dimension $2 \times 2 = 4$. So if you have $5$ of them, what do you know immediately?

Added: Intuitively, the space of $2 \times 2$ matrices has dimension $4$ because a $2 \times 2$ matrix consists of $4$ coordinates which are added separately under the operation of adding $2 \times 2$ matrices. If you've encountered the concept of isomorphism, you can notice that the map
$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix} \to (a,b,c,d)$$
is an isomorphism onto $\mathbb{R}^4$ to prove this formally. In case you have not encountered this concept, note that
$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \right\}$$
forms a basis, since for any given $2 \times 2$ matrix we have
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} = a\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}+ b\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} + c\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} + d\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
and the family is clearly linearly independent.

Comment: Question related to your answer, how do you know $\mathbb R^2$ is size $2\times2$ from the question? I assume $\mathbb M_{2\times2}$ is a matrix of of size $2\times2$ and $\mathbb R^2$ has dimension 2.

Comment: @user95087 I've added some clarification. Does this help?